# iOS - Fetch all photos from device and save them to app

Tags: ios, swift, memory, phasset, photosframework

I would like to fetch all photos that are saved in device and save them to my app and then eventually (if user allow this) delete originals.

This is my whole class I created for this task:

```
class ImageAssetsManager: NSObject {
  let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

  func fetchAllImages() {
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      options.fetchLimit = 5
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    let imageAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(options)
    print(imageAssets.count)
    self.getAssets(imageAssets)
  }

  func getAssets(assets: PHFetchResult) {
    var assetsToDelete: [PHAsset] = []

    assets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (object, count, stop) in
      if object is PHAsset {
        let asset = object as! PHAsset
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,height: asset.pixelHeight)

        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
        options.synchronous = true

        self.imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { [weak self]
          image, info in

          self.addAssetToSync(image, info: info)
          assetsToDelete.append(asset)
          })
      }
    }
    self.deleteAssets(assetsToDelete)
  }

  func addAssetToSync(image: UIImage?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    guard let image = image else {
      return
    }

    guard let info = info else {
      return
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
      let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.95)!
      let fileUrl = info["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let photoRootItem = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.getPhotosRootItem()
        let ssid = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.getSsidInfoByName(ContentManager.sharedInstance.ssid)
        let item = StorageManager.sharedInstance.createFile(imageData, name: fileUrl.absoluteString.fileNameWithoutPath(), parentFolder: photoRootItem!, ssid: ssid!)
      })
    })
  }

  func deleteAssets(assetsToDelete: [PHAsset]){
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
      PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assetsToDelete)
      }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        guard let error = error else {return}
    })
  }
}
```

It's working but my problem is that it's working just for a limited number of photos. When I try it with all I get memory warnings and then app crashed. I know why it is. I know that my problem is that I get all photos to memory and it's too much. I could fetch images with that fetch limit and make it to loop but I am not sure if it is best solution.

I was hoping that with some solution process few photos then release memory and again and again until end. But this change would be somewhere in enumerateObjectsUsingBlock. I am not sure if it helps but I don't even need to get image. I just need to copy image file from device path to my app sandbox path.

What's best solution for this? How to avoid memory warnings and leaks? Thanks

Comment: have u receive any solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dispatch_async calls to dispatch_sync.  Then you will process photos one at a time as you walk through enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, instead of trying to process them all at the same time.